# Magnesium bicarbonate dissociation products

Tags: ions, ionic-compounds

What is the equation for $\ce{Mg(HCO3)2}$ dissociation? Are there more steps because it's a complex substance? Could the possible products be $\ce{MgHCO3+ + HCO3-}$?

Answer (score 2):

Typically dissociation refers to the ions that are formed when a substance dissolves. The most common solvent is water. So in aqueous solution:
$$ \ce{Mg(HCO3)2(s) -> Mg^{2+} + 2HCO3^{-} }$$
The bicarbonate will also form very minor amounts of other aqueous species:
$$\ce{HCO3^{-} <-> H^+ + CO3^{2-}}$$
$$\ce{HCO3^{-} + H^+ <-> H2CO3}$$
$$\ce{H2CO3 <-> CO2 + H2O}$$
The carbon dioxide formed in the last reaction can outgas from the solution as well.